Roadmap for self-learning pure mathematics from high school level onward.
Motivation:- I’m making this post because I know a lot of people who are genuinely interested in learning pure math but have no formal background or experience or help. Many of them are unsure how to start or what order to follow, and they’re often overwhelmed by the sheer number of topics and resources out there or can't even find a road map easily. I thought it could be helpful to create a roadmap to guide self-learners through a structured progression in mathematics.

I’m looking to put together a roadmap for self-learners who want to start studying pure mathematics independently, beginning from high school fundamentals and advancing into more complex areas. This could be incredibly helpful for students and enthusiasts who want a clear, structured path through mathematics that don't have access to a real life guidance.
Here’s what I’m envisioning for each stage of the roadmap:

List of pure math topics/courses and prerequisites for each one.
Recommended books (and lectures if available).
Problem books for further practice, if available.
Advanced pathways for further study.

My hope is that this roadmap could serve as a go-to resource for anyone starting their journey in pure math, giving them a clear sense of direction and valuable resources.
Any guidance, recommended sequences, or additional suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@Bml of course I like it.

@pie I will post my answer after you award the bounty, because other answers deserve it more than mine.

@Bml Still waiting to see it

In mathematics, everybody has to self-study at some point, whether he/she is an enthusiast, a math major, or someone from another field who needs mathematics. The biggest difference between a mathematics enthusiast and others is their goals. If you are ambitious to take over all of mathematics, you might not go anywhere. My advice to enthusiasts is to set an attainable goal, even though this is not something you do once and for all. Learn, discover paths, make your own decisions, and maybe change them later. Unfortunately, a path or a road map is something everyone has to decide for him/herself and it varies among people. However, to envision such a path, one can look at a curriculum from a bachelor's and master's program in mathematics to have some clues and guidance.
In this answer, I provide a list of topics in mathematics with prerequisites, recommended books, and pieces of advice (if I've been learning them) from the high-school level to the undergraduate level (and a little graduate level). I've got this information from my own experience and from reading tons of reviews on Math Stackexchange, Goodreads, Amazon, and the Mathematical Mathematics Memes group on Facebook. I use a top-tier bachelor's program in mathematics as a reference - the program at the University of Bonn (Germany). The curriculum with descriptions, prerequisites, and recommended literature can be found in the Modulhandbuch PDF file here - Bachelor's Program Mathematik - Profile. The file is written in German and the information of each subject is presented in tabular form. The program is advanced and there are gaps that anyone who tries to follow it has to fill in.
High school
First things first. So what and how can one prepare at the high-school stage?
There is a significant gap between mathematics taught in high schools (additionally, Olympiad) and at universities/research. This is due to many differences: In high schools, teachers and students focus more on the calculation aspects of mathematics rather than logical reasoning. Mathematics at this stage is informally taught with intuitions and not-so-rigorous notions. Later in universities, mathematics is taught more seriously with abstract theories, and rigorous definitions, and intuitive things are now not taken advantage of anymore as they require rigorous constructions or proofs (for example, the real numbers, the square root of 2, the continuity of familiar functions...). Terrence Tao wrote about these differences on his blog: There's more to mathematics than rigor and proofs.
However, I wouldn't recommend anyone skip high school mathematics and jump right into some university's mathematics curriculum unless he/she is aware of his/her actions (Peter Scholze wanted to learn arithmetic geometry since he was a high-school student). Although high school mathematics is not ideal for people who want to pursue pure mathematics, there are things at this stage that are essential and can be cherry-picked for later studies.

Mathematical logic: A good starting point is Chapter 1 of Kenneth Rosen's Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications. Mathematical logic is a serious area of mathematics. As you progress in your studies, you might want or need to know more. But for this stage, logic as in Rosen's is enough.
Reading and writing mathematical proofs: Learning mathematical logic solely wouldn't help much at this stage. One must be exposed to a lot of examples of mathematical proofs. I recommend reading Euclid's Elements to familiarize yourself with the proofs. These 2300-year-old texts are still valuable and were translated into English. You don't have to read the entire 13 books of Euclid's Elements.
Euclidean geometry: One doesn't have to reach the Olympiad level of Euclidean geometry. Olympiad mathematics has almost nothing to do with pure mathematics that he/she will learn later (except combinatorics). Of course, Euclid's Elements are still highly recommended to learn Euclidean geometry. On the other hand, one should have a companion while reading Euclid's Elements. Throughout history, mathematicians pointed out some flaws in Euclid's reasoning (to name a few: he abused superpositions, and admitted implicitly that two circles that pass through the center of the other intersect,...). One might want to read Robin Hartshorne's Geometry: Euclid and Beyond to be aware of those flaws in Euclid's Elements, learn about geometric constructions, try new ideas, and have a glimpse at non-Euclidean geometry. Back in high school, I wasted my time learning too much Olympiad geometry (where the figures are usually messy). Now, they (Olympiad geometry stuff) don't help me in my studies.
Coordinate geometry: In later studies (beyond this stage), coordinate geometry dominates Euclidean geometry (synthetic geometry), because geometric intuition doesn't help in higher dimensions and Euclidean geometry has straight lines, rays, line segments, circles, spheres, conic sections, but doesn't discuss other shapes. In coordinate geometry, one needs to know about the equations (implicit forms and parametric forms) of these familiar shapes, their intersections, and formulas of some transformations (dilations, rigid motions, translations, rotations, reflections, ...)
Elementary Algebra: Essentially, elementary algebra in high schools is about manipulating symbols with specific rules, and operations, solving equations and inequations (inequalities). At this stage, one needs to know how to solve linear equations, systems of linear equations, quadratic equations, factor polynomials, algebra identities, and inequalities. You don't learn elementary algebra separately but learn it along with calculus. Cautions: Just as in Olympiad geometry, don't spend too much time with inequalities.
Calculus: Calculus and coordinate geometry go hand in hand. I recommend Sheldon Axler's A Prelude to Calculus (3rd edition) for a first calculus course. The objectives of learning calculus are to familiarize yourself with real numbers (not taking advantage of them), elementary functions (polynomial functions, power functions, exponential functions, logarithm functions, trigonometric functions, and their inverses), the coordinate systems (2D Cartesian, 3D Cartesian, polar, the complex plane), Euclidean vectors, to gain intuitions of limits, continuity, derivatives, and integrations. Back in university, I tried to learn real analysis (the rigorous version of calculus) first and it was mentally painful. I've got over it now, but it is still a painful memory.
Arithmetics/Number Theory: As far as I know, this is often skipped in high schools, and only Olympiad students dive into it. I am not very into number theory, all I learned from number theory are division, greatest common divisors/least common multiples, primes, composites, modular arithmetics, and some classic theorems (Chinese remainder theorem, the fundamental theorem of arithmetics, Fermat's little theorem, Euler's theorem), but they are sufficient for me to learn Abstract Algebra later. However, if you are interested in number-theoretic topics and want to get motivated, you can choose one of the following: Andrew Adler & John E. Coury's The Theory of Numbers: a text and sourcebook of problems (I only read the first 5 chapters of this), Richard Borcherds's Introduction to Number Theory (on YouTube) (The content of this playlist is basic but Borcherds also raised many interesting questions), or Joseph M. Silverman's A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory.
Combinatorics: At this stage, one should learn some counting techniques for counting problems, algorithms, and graph theory. Kenneth Rosen's Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications (just some specific chapters) is also a good book for learning these.
Naive Set Theory: In all textbooks at the undergraduate level, set theory is a prerequisite and many dedicate a chapter or an appendix to it (others assume that readers are already familiar with it). Some recommended sources for learning naive set theory are Paul R. Halmos's Naive Set Theory and the 1st chapter of James Munkres' Topology. To newcomers: Learning about different kinds of infinities in set theory might give you a headache, but that is normal. Don't worry if you don't get it in the first few times. You can come back to it later.

Although to learn is to do, you don't have to force yourself to do all the exercises as some are designed to be challenging or tricky, and you also don't have to read textbooks cover to cover. At this stage, your goal is to prepare yourself for the undergraduate level. As soon as you are comfortable with the prerequisites, switch to the next stage.
Undergraduate
Starting from the undergraduate, mathematics branches out vastly and quickly. It is best to look at the curriculum of a bachelor's program to have an overview because every self-learner needs direction. As wrote at the beginning of this answer, I use the program at the University of Bonn for a reference.
The program has 6 areas. Every student in this program has to pick one main area and courses from other areas to earn sufficient credit points. But they all have to attend some common fundamental courses as follows.
Analysis 1 and 2:

Prerequisites to these courses are set theory, calculus, elementary algebra, and coordinate geometry. Recommended books for learning analysis are

Vladimir A. Zorich's Mathematical Analysis 1 - I use this book because it is new, very comprehensive, and rigorous, has multivariable calculus, contains many examples, and postpones general topology until the 2nd volume.
Stephen Abbott's Understanding Analysis
Terrence Tao's Analysis 1 & 2
Gerald B. Folland's Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications
Tom M. Apostol's Mathematical Analysis


I wouldn't recommend Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis as a first book on analysis, but as a problem source.

Linear Algebra 1 and 2:

Prerequisites to Linear Algebra are set theory, elementary algebra, coordinate geometry, and calculus.
Roughly speaking, the learning of Linear Algebra has two parts: (a) Linear Algebra before eigenvalues (including the theory of systems of linear equations, vector spaces, linear maps, matrices, and determinants) and (b) the rest. I call (a) elementary linear algebra.
In a typical first course on Linear Algebra, vector spaces are associated with familiar fields (the field $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers, the field $\mathbb{C}$ of complex numbers). But once you start learning Abstract Linear Algebra, the fields that are associated with vector spaces can be arbitrary.
Some good first resources for learning Linear Algebra are

Gilbert Strang's lectures on Linear Algebra
Grant Sanderson's Essence of Linear Algebra
For textbooks, I suggest Peter J. Olver's Applied Linear Algebra (The book is modern, inspired by Strang's lectures, and one shouldn't be disappointed just because of the word "applied") for the first book in Linear Algebra.


For a second book in Linear Algebra (this time, it is deeper), I suggest Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right (4th edition) (I used it as my 2nd book on Linear Algebra). Unlike most books on Linear Algebra, in this book, linear maps are the main characters instead of matrices, the theory of systems of linear equations is discussed only in a few exercises, and the determinants are delayed until the final chapter.
In case you want to practice with difficult problems, then I suggest F. Zhang's Linear Algebra - Challenging Problems for Students.

Algorithmic Mathematics 1 and 2:

Prerequisites to these courses are set theory, combinatorics, linear algebra, and a programming language.
One English textbook that the program recommends is notoriously known for being difficult - CLRS's Introduction to Algorithms. If you want a more gentle learning resource, then I suggest Steven Skiena's The Algorithm Design Manual.

General Topology

Prerequisites are set theory, real analysis, and elementary linear algebra.

The program doesn't include general topology (point-set topology). However, general topology - a general theory of continuity - is important for analysis, differential equations, and all other branches of topology. Without a solid foundation in general topology, one would suffer when learning algebraic topology, geometric topology, and differential topology. I don't know how exactly the analysis courses are taught in Bonn, but topology is often included in the teaching of analysis. So it'd be better to learn it in parallel with analysis. Many learners (including math majors) find topology difficult and even annoying. For reading recommendation, I suggest one of the following:

Sidney Morris' Topology without Tears (the most friendly and freely available online)
James Munkres' Topology (the classic and comprehensive)
Loring W. Tu's An Introduction to Manifolds (the appendices)
John M. Lee's Introduction to Topological Manifolds (2nd edition, all appendices, and the first 4 chapters) (focus more on manifolds, a special kind of topological spaces)
Besides, understanding examples and counterexamples in topology is crucial, and a good book for such examples and counterexamples is J. Arthur Seebach Jr. & Lynn Steen's Counterexamples in Topology


I read Morris and Munkres a little (I read them first to overcome my fear of topology) and then dived into Lee's right after I overcame the fear. Meanwhile, I still use Munkres' and Seebach & Steen's for references. Furthermore, topology is hard because proofs in textbooks are usually very hand-wavy. My advice is to work carefully on your/the authors' proofs, calculations, examples, and counterexamples.


The rest of this program is so advanced that it looks more like a master's program, and it contains fewer descriptions and recommended textbooks. It branches out to the following 6 areas. (I've been following B and D).
Area A: Algebra, Number Theory, and Logic
Area A focuses on Abstract Algebra, Number Theory, Representation Theory, and Mathematical Logic.
Abstract Algebra

Prerequisites are naive set theory, Linear Algebra, and a sufficient amount of Number Theory (as I mentioned above)
In Abstract Algebra at the undergraduate level, one learns about fundamental algebra structures such as groups, rings, ideals, fields, vector spaces, modules, and some Galois theory.
Recommended textbooks for self-studying Abstract Algebra are:

John B. Fraleigh & Neal Brand's A First Course in Abstract Algebra (8th edition) - The book is easy to follow, covers a lot of group theory, and exercises are ordered from easy to difficult.
Paolo Aluffi's Algebra: Chapter 0 - I strongly recommend this. The book has 9 chapters and it is also a great introduction to category theory. Abstract Linear Algebra in this book is taken care of better than other books. It also has multilinear algebra and homological algebra.
Dummit & Foote's Abstract Algebra - This is a traditional textbook on Abstract Algebra.


Other textbooks on Abstract Algebra

Serge Lang's Algebra - This classic should not be the first textbook in Abstract Algebra. If you choose it, make sure to use the following A Companion to Lang's Algebra
Michael Artin's Algebra



Multilinear Algebra

Prerequisites are Abstract Linear Algebra and some Abstract Algebra.
A recommended textbook is Werner H. Greub's Multilinear Algebra.

Number Theory

It is still pretty much the same as the previous stage since Number Theory is not emphasized during high school. However, you might try some Algebraic Number Theory and Analytic Number Theory.
A recommended textbook for undergraduates on Algebraic Number Theory is the book with the same title by Frazer Jarvis.
A classic textbook on Analytic Number Theory for undergraduates is Tom M. Apostol's Introduction to Analytic Number Theory

Representation Theory

In representation theory, one studies algebraic structures by representing the elements as linear maps (or matrices) of vector spaces.
Prerequisites are linear algebra and abstract algebra.
Some recommended textbooks are

William Fulton & Joe Harris' Representation Theory: A First Course
Brian C. Hall's Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations: An Elementary Introduction



Mathematical Logic

Prerequisites are propositional and predicate logic.
Recommended textbooks: see Math Stackexchange - Good books on mathematical logic?, or The Open Logic Text

Area B: Analysis and Differential Equations
In area B, one will dive deeper into Real Analysis (including multivariable calculus, the convergence of functional sequences, functional series, multiple integrations, measure theory, differential forms, calculus on manifolds, ...), Complex Analysis, Functional Analysis, and Partial Differential Equations.
Real Analysis

Prerequisites are real analysis from previous courses and general topology.
Recommended textbooks are

Vlamidir A. Zorich's Mathematical Analysis 2 - You might want to learn general topology from other sources instead of the first chapter of this book. The two-volume work is quite comprehensive (it doesn't include Complex Analysis and Functional Analysis).
Sheldon Axler's Measure Theory, Integration & Real Analysis - This book contains a lot of information, ranging from Real Analysis, Measure Theory, Fourier Analysis, and some Functional Analysis.
Elias M. Stein & Rami Shakarchi's Real Analysis: Measure Theory, Integration, and Hilbert Spaces



Measure Theory

Prerequisites are linear algebra, real analysis, naive set theory (you should be familiar with cardinalities and the axiom of choice), and general topology.
A recommended textbook at this stage is this classic:

René L. Chilling's Measures, Integrals and Martingales (2nd edition) - This book is good for self-study as it comes with a solution manual and a sibling book Counterexamples in Measure and Integration.



Complex Analysis

Prerequisites are real analysis and general topology.
Recommended textbooks:

Lars Ahlfors' Complex Analysis - This is the book of complex analysis. One might argue that this is not good for a first book on the topic. However, if you have real analysis and general topology with you, you will be fine.
Read What is a good complex analysis textbook, barring Ahlfors's? for a broader range of choices, but don't use Tristan Needham's Visual Complex Analysis as a first book on Complex Analysis.



Ordinary Differential Equations (ODE) and Partial Differential Equations (PDE)

ODE is not included in the program.
Prerequisites for ODE are real analysis (differential, integral, multivariable calculus) and linear algebra. It would be nice if you know some physics. Prerequisites for PDE are the same as those for ODE and ODE itself.
For ODE, I recommend Morris W. Hirsch & Stephen Smale's Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and Linear Algebra (for more, see Book recommendation for ordinary differential equations)
For PDE, I recommend this textbook: Peter J. Olver's Introduction to Partial Differential Equations. Moreover, Lawrence C. Evans' Partial Differential Equations is also a superb book on the topic according to many readers. Still, it requires much more background, including Measure Theory and Functional Analysis.
Video lectures:

Jason Bramburger's Ordinary Differential Equations
Jason Bramburger's Partial Differential Equations



Functional Analysis

Prerequisites for this are real analysis, linear algebra, and general topology (especially metric spaces).
Recommended textbooks are

Erwin Kreyszig's Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications - Despite the title, the book is rigorous and friendly.
Haim Brezis' Functional Analysis, Sobolev spaces and Partial Differential Equations
Paul R. Halmos' A Hilbert Space Problem Book



Area C: Discrete Mathematics
This area has the least credit points and it emphasizes Discrete Mathematics, Combinatorial Optimization (linear programming, integer programming, ...), and algorithms.
The recommended textbook is B. Korte & J. Vygen's Combinatorial Optimization. Theory and Algorithms.
Area D: Geometry and Topology
In this area, one studies topology and manifolds.
Algebraic Topology

Prerequisites are general topology, abstract algebra (group theory and category theory), and real analysis.
Recommended textbooks (the later, the harder) are

Michael Henle's A Combinatorial Introduction to Topology
John M. Lee's Introduction to Topological Manifolds
William S. Massey's A Basic Course in Algebraic Topology - Munkres also wrote two books on Algebraic Topology, based on another book by Massey.
Allen Hatcher's Algebraic Topology - This is freely available online but I don't recommend it as a first book on the topic. Lee's would be a friendlier start.



Differential Geometry

Prerequisites are linear algebra, multilinear algebra, calculus, multivariable calculus, and general topology.
Recommended textbooks are

Kristopher Tapp's Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces - This book is written for undergraduates, it requires a humble amount of prerequisites, and it is new.
Loring W. Tu's An Introduction to Manifolds (2nd edition)
John M. Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds (2nd edition)


You might want to check out this Reddit thread on Lee vs Tu to decide which book to learn from. Of course, you might take them both.

Analysis and Geometry on Manifolds
I didn't travel this far, but the Modulhandbuch contains some useful information (there are more in the PDF):

Prerequisites are calculus on manifolds (see Zorich's Mathematical Analysis 2), multilinear algebra, and differential geometry.
Recommended textbooks are

John M. Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds (2nd edition)
G. Bredon's Topology and Geometry
R. Abraham, J. Marsden, T. Ratiu: Manifolds, tensor analysis, and applications



I can't say much about the last two areas but the Modulhandbuch can provide better information than I do, including descriptions, prerequisites, and textbooks (although most of them are in German, you might get some clues from their titles). As for areas E & F, one should also learn from other scientific areas that apply them. For example: for area E, it is Numerical Weather Prediction; for area F, it is Mathematical Finance and Computational Neuroscience.
Area E: Numerical and Scientific Computing

Prerequisites are Linear Algebra and Analysis.
Recommended textbook: Richard L. Burden, J. Douglas Faires & Annette M. Burden's Numerical Analysis (10th edition)

Area F: Stochastic
In area F, one will delve into probability theory, statistics, stochastic processes, stochastic analysis, and stochastic differential equations.
Bonus
At the undergraduate level, one might want to dive deeper into some specific but still accessible topics. Here are some I can think of (based on what I saw and my interest).

Galois Theory

Prerequisites: abstract algebra (abstract linear algebra, group theory, ring theory)
The above books on Abstract Algebra already cover some Galois Theory.
Recommended textbooks:

Ian Stewart's Galois Theory
Steven Rotman's Galois Theory




Commutative Algebra

Prerequisites: abstract algebra (linear algebra, ring theory, field theory)
Recommended textbooks:

Michael F. Atiyah & I. G. MacDonald's An Introduction to Commutative Algebra - In this textbook, one learns commutative algebra via exercises.
See Reference request: introduction to commutative algebra




Algebraic Geometry

Most textbooks on Algebraic Geometry are graduate-level. Modern Algebraic Geometry requires a lot of Commutative Algebra, but books like Vakil's develop them gradually.
Prerequisites: it depends on textbooks
Recommended textbooks:

David A. Cox, John Little & Donal O'Shea's Ideals,
Varieties, and Algorithms An Introduction to Computational Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra - Prerequisites are elementary linear algebra, a little abstract algebra (there is one appendix for it), that is almost no prerequisites.
Ravi Vakil's The Rising Sea - Prerequisites are category theory, commutative algebra (like Atiyah & MacDonald's book), and homological algebra.
See Best Algebraic Geometry textbook? (other than Hartshorne)




Dynamical Systems

Prerequisites: real analysis, linear algebra, ODE, PDE
Recommended learning resources:

Jason Bramburger's Dynamical Systems
Steven Strogatz's Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos




Differential Topology

Prerequisites: general topology, smooth manifolds
Recommended textbooks:

John W. Milnor's Topology from a Differential Viewpoint
Victor Guillemin & Alan Pollack's Differential Topology




Homotopy Theory

Prerequisites: general topology and category theory
I recommend Allen Hatcher's Algebraic Topology


Geometric Group Theory

Prerequisites: general topology, group theory, algebraic topology
I recommend Clara Röh's Geometric Group Theory: An Introduction



Some final words
At the undergraduate level, what you learn is not very deep yet. It is only until the graduate level when you choose a narrower area, then things start getting serious. To have a glance at those areas, see the Module Handbook at Master's Program of Mathematics in Bonn (this time, it is in English, since the Master's Program is taught in English)
Some advice and pitfalls for self-learners in mathematics:

If you can't buy a lot of textbooks or don't have institutional access, use platforms like Z-Library, Libgen, Anna's Archive, or ask someone who has institutional access.
Prioritize new textbooks, suitable for self-study, has an errata file (some authors like John M. Lee and Sheldon Axler have errata files for their books on their websites), and solutions are available (in the book or online)
Don't just read the theoretical texts, do exercises also. But don't be mentally blocked by proofs and exercises that are too difficult as things might get illuminated later. One thing I learned from being a self-learner is that one must be able to proceed with uncertainty.
Try reading something other than textbooks and doing something other than exercises sometimes - For example, reading a research paper, or a Wikipedia page, thinking about some open questions (even on your own), delve into something you find interesting. The point is don't just spend time on the prerequisites and then get stuck in the learning loop - the safe zone of self-learners - because if you want to become more like a mathematician, you can't just read textbooks and do exercises.
Mathematics areas are not separated from each other, they are sophistically interdependent. Therefore please don't waste your time by learning them sequentially.

As a self-learner, I wish my learning path had been easier. When I saw your question, I was so excited. I want to become the navigator that I have never had. Thank you for posting this. I hope self-learners will find this answer useful, and I am looking forward to suggestions to improve and update the list. I will update this list as I progress in my self-study.

OMG OMG! I think this might be the longest answer on SE, anyway great answer.

@pie: For several MUCH longer answers, see the several SE answers mentioned in my two comments to this Mathematics Meta SE question.

Side question are you a student in Bonn university ?

@pie I am not, I am just a self-learner. I found the program by chance a few years ago and I've been following it.

Where is ODE? I can't find it

@pie I have just added ODE with a link to the book recommendation.

I added a bonus section for additional topics for undergraduates.

I will try to do Point 1. For Point 2, I give a "classic" textbook, if I can remember one.
After a K-12 education that should include elementary algebra and pre-calculus, you can move on to the freshie topics of calculus and linear algebra. They serve as the basics for the undergraduate method courses in abstract algebra and analysis. These method courses then provide the language needed to cast and formulate postgraduate number theory and geometry. In the senior year, you begin topology and perhaps logic studies.

This prerequisite chart is arranged in 6 rows, with this rows corresponding to 4 years of undergraduate study, followed by 2 years of graduate study.
Freshie topics.

Linear algebra. Textbook: Friedberg, Insel, Spence "Linear algebra", known for its abstraction and rigour.

Linear algebra is the study, initially of vectors and matrices. Then it continues to their abstraction via vector spaces and linear transformations. Highlights include showing that every vector space has a basis, the Rank-Nullity Theorem, the decomposition of a vector space into the direct sum of generalised eigenspaces of a linear operation, and the Spectral Theorem for symmetric and hermitian matrices.

Calculus (prerequisite: pre-calculus). Textbook: Stewart's "Calculus: early transcendentals", which defines the exponential, logarithmic, hyperbolic and trigonometric early in the book, allowing its derivative, integral and applications to be given, when otherwise most examples will be for polynomial or rational functions.

Calculus is the study of the differentiation and integration of functions of a single real variable. It usually requires a student to first learn Cartesian geometry and trigonometry. Definite integrals model lengths, areas, volumes, centre of mass, centre of gravity, moment of inertia, work done etc. The highlight is the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Multivariate calculus (prerequisite: linear algebra and calculus).

Multivariate calculus is the extension of calculus to functions of several real variables. Often there is a focus on functions of 2 or 3 real variables as visualisation is more faithful: when restricted thus, "multivariate calculus" is often called by the old name "vector calculus". Again there is definite integration. Differentiation because partial differential. The highlight is the generalisations of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to 2 or 3 dimensions, such as Gauss's Theorem, Green's Theorem and Stokes' Theorem.
Algebra.

General abstract algebra (prerequisite: linear algebra). Textbook: Lauritzen's "Concrete abstract algebra", which gives algebraic interpretations of number theoretic theorems.

This is a general course on algebraic structures, usually covering groups, rings and fields. Rings act on algebraic structures known as modules. A module over a field is known as a vector space, so some linear algebra is helpful. Typically, there might be individual courses that go in one of these algebraic structures in-depth. I list these below. In a sense there is no real highlight of the course. But when you are studying this topic, you will find that you are introduced to a lot of terminology. In a sense, you are learning vocabulary.

Group theory (prerequisite: elementary number theory).

A course on group theory covers the Sylow Theorems, which are used to classify finite groups. For students who have learned elementary number theory, sometimes group-theoretic concepts are used to interpret number-theoretic theorems. For example, Fermat's little Theorem is interpreted as the divisibility of the order of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$ of the finite field with $p$ elements by the order of any its elements. For students who have not learned number theory, they can regard the concrete examples of the abstract algebra theorems as their foray into number theory. So, in this sense, elementary number theory is concrete abstract algebra. Usually, group actions and symmetric groups are covered. You will learn the classification of finite generated abelian groups. More advanced topics include the representation theory of groups.

Ring and module theory (prerequisite : linear algebra and group theory). Textbook: Lam's "A first course in noncommutative rings", for ring theory. Berrick and Keating's "An introduction to rings and modules: with K-theory in mind", for both ring and module theory.

This course studies commutative and noncommutative rings and the objects they act on, known as "modules". A course focussing only on commutative rings is known as commutative algebra. You will learn different classes of rings, such as fields, principal ideal domains, unique factorisation domains and euclidean domains, and you will learn the inclusion relationships between them. Prime numbers in number theory is now generalised to prime ideals. In module theory, the existence of a basis for every vector space learned in linear algebra is now generalised to the theorem that every module over a divison ring is free. Just as linear transformations may be represented by matrices with respect to choice of bases in the source and target vector spaces, more generally, module homomorphisms between free modules may also be represented by matrices in a similar manner. There are two main extensions of the class of free modules, namely  "projective modules" and "injective modules", which are dual concepts of each other in a precise sense. The continuation of the study of module theory leads to homological algebra.

Field theory (prerequisite: ring theory).

Fields are commutative rings where every nonzero element is invertible. Field theory constitutes it own study distinct from commutative ring theory.

Galois theory (prerequisite : group theory and field theory).

Galois theory is the study of the Galois group, which is the group of automorphisms of a field extension that fixes a ground field.

Lie groups and Lie algebras. (prerequisite: abstract algebra and differential geometry)

Representation theory (prerequisite: abstract algebra)


Analysis.

Mathematical analysis (prerequisite: calculus). Classic: Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis".

When studying calculus, the concepts of differentiation and integration are premissed on the concept of the limit. Depending on how rigorous was your study of calculus, you might have computed limits using Limit Laws and the Squeeze Theorem, or you might have studied the epsilon-delta definition. The epsilon-delta definition properly belongs to the study of mathematical analysis. The course begins with the foundational construction of the real numbers, showing that it is a field extension of the rational numbers that satisfies the Completeness Axiom. My teacher told me that whether the Completeness Axiom is used or not distinguishes whether a theorem properly belongs to mathematical analysis or calculus respectively. Having defined the real numbers and the limit of real functions, the calculus topics of differentation and integration and be revisited rigorously. The point of this course is rigour and the study of mathematical proofs. You will distinguish pointwise and uniform convergence. You will distinguish between conditional and absolute convergence. Often a study of Taylor's Remainder Theorem will be included.

Real analysis (prerequisite: mathematical analysis). Textbook: **Folland's "Real Analysis", for conciseness.

Real analysis defines the Lebesgue integral, which approximates functions with respect to the codomain via characteristic functions and step-wise functions. In contrast, the Riemannian integral learned in a mathematical analysis course approximates functions with respect to the domain via thin and tall rectangles. So real analysis includes measure theory, leading to the definition of the Lebesgue integral.

Complex analysis (prerequisite: mathematical analysis). Classic: Ahlfors's "Complex analysis".

Complex analysis is the study of a single complex variable. The basic theorem is that any solution of the Cauchy-Riemann equations can be expanded as a complex power series at any point. Being a solution of the Cauchy-Riemann equations is the definition of complex differentiable. Being expandable as a complex power series at any point is the definition of "complex analytic". So the basic theorem says that complex differentiability and complex analyticity are equivalent. The relevant integration is the contour integral, leading to the Cauchy Integral Formula. Applications of contour integration are sometimes given to the computation of the principal value of real integrals. A more advanced course ends with the Uniformization Theorem.

Fourier analysis (prerequisite: mathematical analysis). Textbook: Stein and Shakarchi's "Fourier Analysis: an introduction", for its beautiful writing and ease of understanding.

Functional analysis (prerequisite: linear algebra and mathematical analysis). Textbook: Stein and Shakarchi's "Functional analysis: Introduction to further topics in analysis", for its beautiful writing.


Functional analysis is the study of infinite-dimensional vector spaces. In this case, often the raw algebraic structure is insufficient, so additional topological structure is required. Banach spaces come equipped with a norm. Hilbert spaces have even more structure and come equipped with an inner product. $L^p$-spaces are given an example of Banach spaces. The $L^2$-space is a Hilbert space.
16. Differential equations (prerequisite: linear algebra and calculus).
Often calculus courses cover some differential equations. However, there are entire courses on differential equations where qualitative behaviour of the solution of differential equations are studied. You learn equilibrium solutions and whether they are stable or unstable. The phase space is used in the qualitative study of differential equations. More advanced course may study the so-called "weak solutions" of differential equations. For example, the $L^p$-spaces learned in functional analysis are generalisation to Hölder spaces, that are spaces of weak solutions.
Number theory

Elementary number theory.

You may or may not have learned elementary number theory during K-12. Usually elementary number theory is covered as a topic in competition math.
18. Analytic number theory (prerequisite: elementary number theory and complex analysis).
19. Algebraic number theory (elementary number theory, ring theory, Galois theory). Textbook: Marcus's "Number fields"', for dealing with many special cases of reciprocity theorems successively.
Geometry.

Elementary Euclidean and non-Euclidean geometry.

Differential geometry (prerequisite: multivariate calculus and linear algebra and differential equations).

Algebraic geometry (prerequisite: ring and module theory and elementary analytic geometry) Lecture notes: Vakil's "Rising sea"

Complex geometry (prerequisite: several complex variables, differential geometry and algebraic geometry). Textbook: Voisin.


Logic.

General propositional and predicate logic. Textbook: Enderton, from the Berkeley school.

Naive set theory.

Computability theory.

Set theory (prerequisite: naive set theory and predicate logic).

Model theory (abstract algebra and predicate logic). Textbook: **Marker's "Model theory: an introduction"


Culminates in Morley's Categoricity Theorem.

Proof theory.

Category theory (prerequisite: abstract algebra.) Textbook: Riehl's "Category theory in context".


You will study categories, functors, natural transformations, limits and colimits, then adjoint functors. Highlights include the commutativity of left adjoints with colimits, the commutativity of right adjoints with limits, and the Adjoint Functor Theorem.
Topology

General pointset topology (prerequisite: naive set theory) Textbook: Munkres.

Algebraic topology (prerequisite: general pointset topology and abstract algebra). Textbook: May, for its conciseness and category theoretic approach.

Homotopy theory (prerequisite: category theory and algebraic topology).

Homological algebra (prerequisite: module theory)



Could I get some help to understand the down votes? I have tried to answer the question.

Whoever gave the negative feedback to this post must post their own version. As a self learner myself, I have the same question in my mind as the OP. Most of the questions and topics posted on MSE are completely new to me and I have often wondered, without the help of a professor or similar academic guidance, what is the logical way to acquire knowledge of new topics that is sensible.

I didn't downvote this answer. One thing I don't like about this answer is that although the list is quite comprehensive, it doesn't show any sensible path to learning these.

Perhaps it may be clearer to draw a directed graph with an arrow from a prerequisite to more advanced topic. @Duong Ngo, could you recommend how I could improve my answer to provide such a sensible path? May I know what sort of "sensible path" are you looking for?

@ColinTan I quote OP: "Many of them are unsure how to start or what order to follow, and they’re often overwhelmed by the sheer number of topics and resources out there or can't even find a road map easily. " If we follow these criteria, then topics that are prerequisites must come first, and they must contain advice, common pitfalls...

in response, I have added a paragraph that explains how the topics I have listed fit in a usual math curriculum.

@DuongNgo, could you give me an example of what sort of advice or common pitfall you might be looking for?

I have not downvoted this but you have many topics on this list that professional mathematicians don't necessarily have nor need. The path someone takes depends upon their interests and where they study. @Marlene, whose post was downvoted and, consequently, deleted made the most sense. Go to a real university site and look at the requirements for a mathematics degree. After you have completed those, if ever, ask again. But you won't have to ask again.

@ColinTan I will use general topology as an example. I would advise learners to take general topology seriously because it is a general theory of continuity and is important for mathematical analysis, PDE, and all of the other branches of topology. One disadvantage of learning general topology via textbooks is that proofs and calculations are often hand-wavy. Therefore learners should work carefully on their/authors' proofs and calculations. Furthermore, understanding examples and counterexamples in topology is crucial. I am also working on an answer and it is gonna be very long.

I actually agree with @Marlene's answer.

@pie, could we ask what you are looking for? I noticed you asked a similar question on the Philosophy Stack Exchange. I saw that the answers there were more verbose so I started adding paragraphs of description to every course that I wrote. But I am not sure if that's what you are looking for.

@ColinTan Your answer is great but it need more organisation you can do use --- to make lines after each topic  and use bulleted list ctrl+U to list each requirement for each topic.

I am looking for a list like this :
1- pre clac: books:..., Lectures/videos:..., Problem books:...,
$$ $$
2-calculus: pre req:...., books:..., Lectures/videos:..., Problem books:... Advanced calc:....
$$ $$
3-linear algebra  pre req:...., books:..., Lectures/videos:..., Problem books:... Advanced linear algebra:....
etc

Also It would be better if you change the arrange all together, rearranging the topics in fields like that seem confusing to newbies in math, I would recommend you organize them so the topics that are prerequisites come first.

I have decided to keep my list organised by area of math, but included a prereq chart to explain the order of study. The areas I state are in general order of succesive study with algebra and analysis covered first before their applications to number theory, geometry and topology. The self-learner can learn the first course from each mathematical area first.

Introduction
In my experience, one of the biggest challenges in self-studying mathematics is the uncertainty that comes from not knowing if your solutions are correct. To address this, I’ve focused on resources that include solution manuals or have solutions readily available online. These resources allow learners to check their work, identify mistakes, and build confidence in their understanding as they progress.

Suggested Sequence for Learning Mathematics
Below is a suggested sequence of topics along with recommended resources. The goal here is to guide learners from foundational topics up to more advanced subjects, all while ensuring they have access to solutions to verify their understanding. I validated that each book has an easily accessible solution manual; however, not all of them are free.

Step 1: Building a Foundation

Precalculus

Book: Precalculus: Graphical, Numerical, Algebraic by Demana, Waits, Foley, Kennedy (solution manual available).


Calculus

Book: Essential Calculus: Early Transcendentals by James Stewart (solution manual available).


Linear Algebra (Introduction)

Book: Elementary Linear Algebra by Ron Larson (solution manual available).


Probability & Statistics (Introductory)

Book: Probability and Statistics for Engineering and the Sciences by Jay L. Devore (solution manual available).




Step 2: Diving Deeper into Core Concepts

Abstract Algebra

Book: Abstract Algebra (3rd Edition) by David S. Dummit and Richard M. Foote (solution manual available).


Real Analysis

Book: Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Walter Rudin (solution manual available).
Alternate Book: Understanding Analysis by Stephen Abbott (solution manual available).


Introduction to Topology

Book: Topology by James R. Munkres (solution manual available).


Linear Algebra (Deeper Exploration)

Book: Linear Algebra Done Right by Sheldon Axler (solution manual available).




Step 3: Exploring Specialized Areas

Ordinary Differential Equations

Book: Elementary Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems by Boyce & DiPrima (solution manual available).


Mathematical Logic & Set Theory

Book: A Mathematical Introduction to Logic by Herbert Enderton (solution manual available).


Probability Theory (Beyond Basics)

Book: A First Course in Probability by Sheldon Ross (solution manual available).




Step 4: Expanding into Further Topics

Functional Analysis

Book: Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications by Erwin Kreyszig (solution manual available and odd numbered questions in back of book).


Algebraic Topology

Book: Algebraic Topology by Allen Hatcher (solution manual available).


Complex Analysis

Book: Complex Analysis by Lars Ahlfors (solution manual available).


Measure Theory & Integration

Book: Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications by Gerald B. Folland (solution manual available).




Final Thoughts
Anyone who works through the above sequence should be in a strong position to pursue more specialized areas or research interests independently. At this stage, learners will likely have developed the confidence to explore new mathematical fields on their own.
I hope someone finds this helpful, and I'd be happy to hear any feedback or suggestions!

Your list is great but it only misses to write in a clear manner  that the list is organized by pre-requites (i.e just follow the list and you won't miss something) and lectures videos. If you could add problem books for further practice then your answer will be excellent.

Also can you link to books and the solution manual.

@Pie Problem with linking to books is you can just find these books by typing in the name and then pdf afterwards, so I don't want to link people to a store when they can just find them on google. For the order, it does have a sequential ordering of steps. The books I mentioned have plenty of problems, so I don't see a need to list more problem books. I'm also not big on lectures generally. I'm pretty happy with the list, but I understand if you don't think its worth the bounty.

Munkres' Topology seems a bit more advanced than the other books you've listed in Step 2. A better fit, in my opinion, would be Introduction to Topology by Mendelson or some of the other books listed in this MSE answer.

@DaveL. I'm partial to Munkres' book because of the free solution set

Formal Language Theory

Proof Theory
Grammars
Category Theory
Equivalence with programming

Measure Theory

Coding Theory
Information Theory
Probability
Statistics

Number Theory

Integers
Rational Numbers
Real numbers

Algebras

Algebraic variety
Vector space
Algebra
Tensor

Topology, Fiber Bundles, Manifolds, Differential Manifolds, ...
Complex Numbers, Calculus, Multivariable calculus (should be easy since you already know differential geometry)
This is by no means exhaustive, I have just noticed most of math is easier once you understand it is basically just a bunch of rules for rewriting symbols so learning that might be a good first step. I generally think it is easier to learn the things that have the least restrictions first and then learning applications of it. So learn measure theory first and then after that dabble in probability, for example. Sometimes this means some definitions uses things you don't know yet, but then you can do a directed google and only learn that thing and continue, or wave it away for now.
